# How to sum value in javascript array object form specific search id?

Tags: javascript

I have javascript array object as below. My need is to sum value base on seach id in the array object.

```
var array = [
{ id: 1, val: 10 }, 
{ id: 2, val: 25 }, 
{ id: 3, val: 20 }, 
{ id: 1, val: 30 }, 
{ id: 1, val: 25 }, 
{ id: 2, val: 10 }, 
{ id: 1, val: 20 }
],
```

For example sum of value for id 1 is 10 + 30 + 25 + 20 = 85 , It may be something link linq but I'm not sure in javascript. Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Please show expected ouput

Comment: Eg. I need to sum value at id=1. So output must be 10 + 30 + 25 + 20 = 85

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a combination of filter and reduce to get the result you want:

```
sumOfId = (id) => array.filter(i => i.id === id).reduce((a, b) => a + b.val, 0);
```

Usage:

```
const sumOf1 = sumOfId(1); //85
```

Reading material:

[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 2):

A way to do it with a traditional `for` loop

```
var array = [
  { id: 1, val: 10 }, 
  { id: 2, val: 25 }, 
  { id: 3, val: 20 }, 
  { id: 1, val: 30 }, 
  { id: 1, val: 25 }, 
  { id: 2, val: 10 }, 
  { id: 1, val: 20 }
];

var sums = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var obj = array[i];
  sums[obj.id] = sums[obj.id] === undefined ? 0 : sums[obj.id];
  sums[obj.id] += parseInt(obj.val);
}

console.log(sums);
```

[running example](https://jsfiddle.net/wv0yuoj3/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your kind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` and `findIndex()`

```js
var array = [
{ id: 1, val: 10 }, 
{ id: 2, val: 25 }, 
{ id: 3, val: 20 }, 
{ id: 1, val: 30 }, 
{ id: 1, val: 25 }, 
{ id: 2, val: 10 }, 
{ id: 1, val: 20 }
];
let res = array.reduce((ac,a) => {
  let ind = ac.findIndex(x => x.id === a.id);
  ind === -1 ? ac.push(a) : ac[ind].val += a.val;
  return ac;
},[])
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind.

Answer (score 1):

JS noob here ... I guess something like this should be here too :-)

```
let newArray = {}
array.forEach((e) => {
    !newArray[e.id] && (newArray[e.id] = 0);
    newArray[e.id] += e.val;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on the array and check the ids.

```js
var array = [
  { id: 1, val: 10 }, 
  { id: 2, val: 25 }, 
  { id: 3, val: 20 }, 
  { id: 1, val: 30 }, 
  { id: 1, val: 25 }, 
  { id: 2, val: 10 }, 
  { id: 1, val: 20 }
];

var sum = 0;
var id = 1;

$.each(array, function(index, object){
  if (object.id == id) {
    sum += object.val;
  }
});

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind.

Answer (score 0):

You could take `GroupBy` from `linq.js` with a summing function.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, val: 10 }, { id: 2, val: 25 }, { id: 3, val: 20 }, { id: 1, val: 30 }, { id: 1, val: 25 }, { id: 2, val: 10 }, { id: 1, val: 20 }],
    result = Enumerable
        .From(array)
        .GroupBy(null, null, "{ id: $.id, sum: $$.Sum('$.val') }", "$.id")
        .ToArray();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) you can get the sum for each id like so. This also uses [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to have quicker access to properties.

```js
const data=[{id:1,val:10},{id:2,val:25},{id:3,val:20},{id:1,val:30},{id:1,val:25},{id:2,val:10},{id:1,val:20}];

const res = data.reduce((a,{id,val})=>{
  return a.set(id, (a.get(id)||0) + val);
}, new Map())

console.log(res.get(1));
console.log(res.get(2));
```

If you wanted to output all the sums, then you need to use [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
const data=[{id:1,val:10},{id:2,val:25},{id:3,val:20},{id:1,val:30},{id:1,val:25},{id:2,val:10},{id:1,val:20}];

const res = Array.from(
  data.reduce((a,{id,val})=>{
    return a.set(id, (a.get(id)||0) + val);
  }, new Map())
);

console.log(res);
```

If the format should be similar as to your original structure, you need to add a [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) afterwards to transform it.

```js
const data=[{id:1,val:10},{id:2,val:25},{id:3,val:20},{id:1,val:30},{id:1,val:25},{id:2,val:10},{id:1,val:20}];

const res = Array.from(
  data.reduce((a,{id,val})=>{
    return a.set(id, (a.get(id)||0) + val);
  }, new Map())
).map(([id,sum])=>({id,sum}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, introducing an `Array.prototype.sum` helper:

```js
Array.prototype.sum = function (init = 0, fn = obj => obj) {
    if (typeof init === 'function') {
        fn = init;
        init = 0;
    }

    return this.reduce(
        (acc, ...fnArgs) => acc + fn(...fnArgs), 
        init
    );
};

// .sum usage examples
console.log(
    // sum simple values
    [1, 2, 3].sum(),
    // sum simple values with initial value
    [1, 2, 3].sum(10),
    // sum objects
    [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }].sum(obj => obj.a),
    // sum objects with initial value
    [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }].sum(10, obj => obj.a),
    // sum custom combinations
    [{ amount: 1, price: 2 }, { amount: 3, price: 4 }]
        .sum(product => product.amount * product.price)
);

var array = [{ id: 1, val: 10 }, { id: 2, val: 25 }, { id: 3, val: 20 }, { id: 1, val: 30 }, { id: 1, val: 25 }, { id: 2, val: 10 }, { id: 1, val: 20 }];

// solutions
console.log(
    array.filter(obj => obj.id === 1).sum(obj => obj.val),
    array.filter(({id}) => id === 1).sum(({val}) => val),
    array.sum(({id, val}) => id === 1 ? val : 0)
);
```

**references:**

- [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) used in `sum(obj => obj.val)`
- [Object destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) used in `({id}) => id === 1`
- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) used in `(acc, ...fnArgs) => acc + fn(...fnArgs)`
- [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) used in `id === 1 ? val : 0`